# Find the value $I = \int\limits_2^3 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {{x^3} - 3{x^2} + 5} }}} $

Tags: integration

Let $I = \int\limits_2^3 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {{x^3} - 3{x^2} + 5} }}} $ find the value of $\left[ {I + \sqrt 3 } \right] $ {where [.] represent greatest integral function}

Let $T(x)={{x^3} - 3{x^2} + 5}$, $T'\left( x \right) = {x^3} - 3{x^2} + 5 = 3{x^2} - 6x = 3x\left( {x - 2} \right) > 0,x \in \left( {2,3} \right)$

$T(x)$ is increasing for $x\in(2,3)$

Not able to proceed further

Comment: Hint: Since the function is increasing, can you bound its integral by choosing a couple of values for $x$?

Comment: We have $f(2)=1$ and $f(3)=\frac1{\sqrt5}$ and $f$ is smooth, with an inflection point. Hence a linear approximation gives $I=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ and we can reasonably think that $[I+\sqrt3]=[2.4556\cdots]=2$ (but this is not a proof).

Comment: $T(2)=1$ & $T(3)=5$, $\int\limits_2^3 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt 5 }}}  < I < \int\limits_2^3 {dx}  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{{\sqrt 5 }} < I < 1$

Comment: Make a series expansion of the integrand to $O\left(\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^3\right)$. This will give you for the integral $\frac{41}{10 \sqrt{30}}=0.748554$ while the exact solution is $0.735284$

Comment: Note: rewriting the cubic as $x^{3}-3x^{2}+5=(x-2)^{3}+3(x-2)^{2}+1$, we can immediately see that this cubic is strictly positive for $x\ge2$ by algebra alone. No need for calculus. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Built around $x=\frac 52$ the series expansion of the integrand is
$$2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{15}} \left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{5}
   \sqrt{\frac{6}{5}} \left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}
   \left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^3-\frac{111}{50} \sqrt{\frac{3}{10}}
   \left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^4+O\left(\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^5\right)$$
Integrate (some terms will disappear because of the symmetry) and you have a very good approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have an idea to compute that integral. Let,
$$I(t)=\int_{2}^{3}\sqrt{x^3-3x^2+5t} dx$$
Notice that $I'(1)$ gives the required integral but a constant term in front.

Now we are only required to evaluate $I(t)$.
Note that for all $t\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in [2,3]$, $5t>x^{3}-3x^{2} \implies \frac{x^3-3x^2}{5t} <1$.
$$I(t)=\sqrt{5t}\int_{2}^{3}\sqrt{1+\frac{x^3-3x^2}{5t}} dx$$
Since, $\frac{x^3-3x^2}{5t} <1$ we can use [fractional binomial theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-binomial-theorem/#:%7E:text=The%20binomial%20theorem%20for%20integer,and%20other%20applications%20in%20calculus)
Now at last you will be left with a summation, whose bounds are easily predictable by adjusting the sum to another well known convergent sums. This easily enables you to calculate your required floor value.